# Keycloak 403 (Forbidden) on Keycloak.loadUserProfile()

Tags: angularjs, keycloak

I am new to Keycloak. I have tried to get the user information using below code:

```
keycloakAuth.loadUserProfile().success(function(profile) {
  debugger
        console.log(profile);
    }).error(function(res) {
      debugger
        console.log('Failed to load profile');
    });
```

installation json is :

```
{
  "realm": "CheckRealm",
  "realm-public-key": "MIIBIjASDFJJK677132HJJAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAgo4deAfr8BeqWOiCsddwMtH5nh8EK2cKIeInpt7LnoCyMsGj1HTP835HpslOURrR6Bgc42V7r6J/MIHqx3+KESTqpcQSe9ll6eUjzaMbIX2GPmy9OnviH6srUgOlDAKhL+/SDh/iv8RfErAPO9cxnoBWUUTyfyes1YRn34KILBdHZoaWk5mteJx9aV4bfA5tGTT6aF8o1NkCX1OUfXiaAD5sqKZV5vbI+QsOUsNshvGfE5JR2EpwZbWH/vRQVusxLURjC51v96ieQ8zUME5LwAQ0TgZcspHTb4Y+KuYRTuDQKuxRUYFeNbvqUGeT2s2sHMmWOQIDAQAB",
  "auth-server-url": "https://something.com/auth",
  "url": "https://something.com/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "sample-tracker",
  "clientId": "sample-tracker",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "bnmbsdk87wq"
  }
}
```

I got the mentioned error :Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Answer (score 9):

To solve this situation you need to configure your keycloak or RedHat Single Sign-On (if you are using the supported version).

1. Open the keycloak admin console, for example: http://localhost:8180/auth/admin. Then click on Configure > **clients** and select the **account client**. The account client **must be enabled**.
2. Next, still in Configure > **clients**, select the client that you are trying to access and click on the scope tab. Add the view-profile role of account application.
3. The user also needs to have this permission.